# How to make a function that will output the clap if the numbers have elements 2, 4 or 8?

Tags: regex, list, function, lambda, regularized

Each number call that contains a value (2,4,8) will output "Clap", if not "No clap"

**Call**

```
def clapping (number)

def clapping (772)
```

**output:**

```
"Clap"
```

I made the program, but it seems something is wrong. Can I ask for help to check which is wrong

```
import re

def clapping(number):
    return "Clap" if re.findall("[248]+",number) else "No Clap"

print(clapping(779))
```

Comment: You don't use `def` when you're calling the function with an argument.

Comment: So i don't need to use def in running the program? Is it like that, sir?

Comment: You use `def` when defining a function, not when calling it. you don't write `def clapping(772)`, you just write `clapping(772)`

Comment: Sir, I want to ask. Which part in my program that wrong ?

Comment: I posted an answer below.

Comment: Sir, is findall function can only read strings?

Comment: Yes, didn't I say that in my answer below? All the regexp functions only work on strings.

Comment: Yes sir, I understand now

Comment: Yeni, when deciding which tags to include you need to think how they might be used to filter your question in or out in searches. Might someone want to see questions with a "regex" tag? Yes, definitely. What about "list", "function" and the others? I don't think so. Among questions that were concerned with lists, for example, only a tiny fraction would have that tag, so why search on it? The same  for the others. What about readers who want to see Python questions? There are lots of those, but they may miss your question. I suggest you have two tags: "python" and "regex".

Answer (score 2):

The regexp functions require a string to search, so you have to convert the number to a string with `str(number)`.

There's also no need to use `findall()`. You only need to know if the regexp matches one time, you don't need a list of all the matches. Similarly, you don't need the `+` quantifier, since matching a single character is enough.

```
def clapping(number):
    return "Clap" if re.search("[248]",str(number)) else "No Clap"
```